# Emacs detaching from launcher

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher, emacs

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and I am having an issue with emacs and the Unity launcher. When I start up emacs from the launcher it opens a new window but the typical little arrows do not appear on either side of the emacs icon. When I minimize the emacs window clicking the Unity icon does not maximize it, it opens a new window instead. So once I have minimized emacs there is no way to retrieve my current session. Any ideas on what might be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/690308) of bamf (the window matching library of ubuntu).

Currently I know no workaround for having the emacs icon in the launcher, but I can tell you that when you start emacs from the command-line, you do get a working launcher icon for the current session (arrows, focus, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for linking the error. Strangely enough I restarted my computer a few minutes ago and when I started up emacs the problem was gone. Not really sure why but I guess the problem is fixed :P